# e_mark_point で min、avg、max の異なる値を返す方法は?

Tags: r

このデータがあります:

```
library(echarts4r)

x <- c(10, 20, 30, 45, 46, 50)
y <- c(12, 25, 36, 46, 49, 59)

matrixinc1 <- data.frame(x, y)

near_line <- function(matriz) {
  diferenca <- abs(matriz[, 1] - matriz[, 2])
  indice <- which.min(diferenca)
  return(matriz[indice, , drop = FALSE])
}

near <- near_line(matrixinc1)
near

matrixinc1 |>
  e_charts(x) |>
  e_line(x) |>
  e_line(y) |>
  e_mark_point(data = near)
```

x 値を 45 で表し、y 値を 46 で表そうとしましたが、グラフ内でこの調整を行うことができませんでした。マーカーが重ならないようにこれを行うことは可能ですか?

私もこれを試してみました：

```
matrixinc1 |>
  e_charts(x) |>
  e_line(x) |>
  e_line(y) |>
  e_mark_point("x", data = near[,1]) |> 
  e_mark_point("y", data = near[,2])
```

この：

```
 matrixinc1[["test"]] <- near$x

avg <- list(
  type = "value",
  value = near$x,  # Atribui o valor de near[,1] à propriedade 'value'
  name = "AVG"
)

matrixinc1 |>
  e_charts(x) |>
  e_line(x) |>
  e_line(y) |>
  e_mark_point("x", data = avg)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript 向けのドキュメントの [markPoint](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-line.markPoint) を参考にした記述例を下記に示します。

```
library(echarts4r)

x <- c(10, 20, 30, 45, 46, 50)
y <- c(12, 25, 36, 46, 49, 59)

matrixinc1 <- data.frame(x, y)

near_line <- function(matriz) {
    diferenca <- abs(matriz[, 1] - matriz[, 2])
    indice <- which.min(diferenca)
    return(matriz[indice, , drop = FALSE])
}

near <- near_line(matrixinc1)

near_x <- list(coord = c(near$x, near$x), value = near$x)
near_y <- list(coord = c(near$x, near$y), value = near$y)

matrixinc1 |>
    e_charts(x) |>
    e_line(x) |>
    e_line(y) |>
    e_mark_point("x", data = near_x, symbolRotate = 35) |>
    e_mark_point("y", data = near_y, symbolRotate = -35)
```

[image: 出力画像]